# batch script if exist xcopy

Tags: file, batch-file, xcopy

I need a little help with one batch script and `xcopy`. I have a folder with a lot of different folders inside. For example: "Test" is the primary directory and inside I have `New folder 1`, `New folder 2`, `New folder 3`... Every week these folders have to copy to different servers.

My script is:

```
if exist "%dir%\New folder 1" (
  xcopy %dir%\New folder 1 C:\Users\user1\New folder1 /i /q /s /y /z
  echo New folder 1 copied successfully
) 
if exist "%dir%\New folder 2" (
  xcopy %dir%\New folder 2 C:\Users\user1\New folder2 /i /q /s /y /z
  echo New folder 2 copied successfully
)
```

I need to update my script to show me the errors on `cmd` when `xcopy` cannot copy some files.

Comment: You need to put your script into a code block, to make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding this correctly, let me know if I'm wrong.

XCopy should throw errors itself if there's an issue to do with permissions etc. If it's just that something doesn't exist, just add an `ELSE` to your `IF` statements and echo whatever error you want.

Sidenote: You have a typo in your script, you're checking the existence of `New Folder 1` twice, not `New Folder 1` and `New Folder 2`. Not sure if that's just on SO, but I thought I'd tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Xcopy returns an error code for the last action, you can check this with the `&&` and `||` operator:

```
@echo off &setlocal
if exist "%dir%\New folder 1" xcopy "%dir%\New folder 1" "C:\Users\user1\New folder1" /i /q /s /y /z && echo New folder 1 copied successfully || echo copied NOT successfully
if exist "%dir%\New folder 2" xcopy "%dir%\New folder 2" "C:\Users\user1\New folder2" /i /q /s /y /z && echo New folder 2 copied successfully || echo copied NOT successfully
```

Note: always put double quotes around path names with space(s).